# How to avoid getting Press ctrl + c to cancel all filesystem checks in process?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.10

I am very new to Linux and
I have one question for you all. I have installed fresh Ubuntu 20.10 on my Asus laptop and I have 1 TB of HDD. The following information will be of my HDD partition.

```
/dev/sda1 140G 8,8G 124G 7% /
/dev/sda5 242G 61M 230G 1% /Blue
/dev/sda4 976M 7,8M 968M 1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3 517G 73M 491G 1% /Red
```

Now every time when I boot my system it says ***"Press ctrl + c to cancel all filesystem checking in the process"*** Does this notification is harmful for laptop? What to do for avoiding that message every time when I boot.

Secondly I have make partition where ***sda1 is for Linux OS files***, ***sda5 is one drive named Blue*** and ***sda3 is another drive named Red*** (To store the personal files/data). I do not see those tow drives listed on left side of the panel in Files. But I see those drives as a folders in Other Locations/ Computer / drives name. I have no issue accessing those from there but why it is not listed in Files? Or it would be like that only in Linux? Looking forward to hearing.
Thanks

Comment: How long is it taking to get to the login screen? Are you saying the check is making the boot slow? It’s normal for Ubuntu to check the filesystem when it starts and that may be noticeable with an HDD. If you look in the fstab file (sudo cat /etc/fstab) there is probably a line for each partition. The last entry on each line should be a 1 or a 0. A 1 means check the filesystem at boot. A 0 means don’t check. Generally the default is check the root filesystem only, /dev/sda1 in your case.

Comment: Conventionally in Linux you keep your personal files in the home directory but you don’t have to do that. You can mount your data partitions, /red and /blue inside home instead or you can make one of them your home directory and create a directory structure from there. It’s a bit of a trap to create too many partitions when you install. Some people prefer a single / partition for the whole disk. Others prefer a / partition and a /home partition. There are arguments for and against both

Comment: Correction. The numbers in the fstab file can be 2 or 3 or 4 ... they just indicate the order in which the partitions are checked although it’s unusual to see anything more than 0 or 1

Comment: ```/ was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=2416d1de-e7e5-40c9-a45a-d939d6f517c6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
 /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=7A83-D8FD  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
 /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=3e743a03-a5fa-4da5-84be-c471d658647a /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
 swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=b468c770-08c9-4415-bfb0-2642bfeb9ac1 none            swap    sw              0       0``` This is the output I got. Do you think I am in danger?

Comment: I think what you are seeing is normal behaviour for a HDD installation but you haven’t said how long the checking process takes. If there was something wrong you’d expect an error message. Your fstab file appears to have two drives with a setting of 1 for the filesystem check order but it’s hard to see in your comment above. I’m not sure what happens with two entries of 1 for the order so you might want to change the /boot/EFI partition to 0. There is little point checking that partition. Unless I found error messages in the logs I’d press Ctrl +c on most boots but let it complete occasionally

Comment: I do not see any error messages while booting and the file checking is not taking much longer. And how to change /boot/EFI partition to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to edit the the /etc/fstab file:

In this case let’s check that the file needs editing first and to do that safely make a backup copy in your home directory. Open the terminal and use the following command

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab fstab
```

Then you need to open the fstab file in your text editor and check the line containing the /boot/EFI entry. Doing it this way should display the text so that the lines are not merged together. If you don’t have a 1 at the end of the /boot/EFI line then there is nothing extra to do.

If you do need to edit the file then do the following in your terminal:

1. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
2. Using the arrow keys on your keyboard move around the file and make any changes.
3. To save the edits press Ctrl + O (letter O not number 0)
4. To exit nano press Ctrl + X
5. To check you haven’t messed up `sudo findmnt --verify --verbose` If you get no error messages all is well.

If you do get errors replace the fstab file with the backup and come back here for more help:

```
sudo cp fstab /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Although the message ("Press ctrl + c ..") is gone while booting but I got message while executing the command  ```sudo find mnt --verify --verbose``` message : ```find: unknown predicate `--verify'```

Comment: My mistake, it’s findmnt not find mnt. Updated above

Comment: Yup no errors now and on. Thanks.